# Clojure - test a Pedestal route

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, pedestal

I would like to write tests for a Pedestal web-service.

If I have :

```
(defn pong
  [request]
  (ring-resp/response "pong"))

(defroutes routes[[["/" {:get pong}]]])
```

How would I write a test for that ?

```
(deftest alive-system
  (testing "ping-pong route"
    ;; How do I test my route ?
    ;; If possible :
    ;; - I would like to have direct access to it
    ;;   ie. no need to bind pedestal to a port would be nice
    ;; - The ability to omit some interceptors would be nice also,
    ;;   as it would allow me to receive plain Clojure data structures
    ;;   instead of, for instance, JSON which I would have to parse.
    ...)
```

**Edit**:
Here is what I tried :

```
(deftest alive-system
  (testing "ping-pong route"
    (let [response (my-other.ns/routes (mock/request :get "/ping"))]
      (is (= (:status response) 200))
      (is (= (:body response) "pong")))))
```

But I get an exception :

```
ERROR in (alive-system) (service_test.clj:13)
Uncaught exception, not in assertion.
expected: nil
  actual: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-mock?

Comment: @ez121sl I did, I am using it with a compojure app already, let me edit my question.

Comment: Compojure's `defroutes` creates a ring handler or some such thing. Pedestal's version is apparently different. Their sample test is not using ring-mock: https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/samples/hello-world/test/hello_world/service_test.clj

Comment: @ez121sl Thanks for the link, that looks like the standard way of doing tests with Pedestal, however I am quite sure it is possible also with ring.mock ( https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/issues/319 ), and I would prefer to keep my options open at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after asking on the issue I linked `ohpaulez` replied :

> @nha - Thanks for using Pedestal! Sorry your question didn't get an
>   answer on StackOverflow - I don't think anyone monitors SO for
>   Pedestal questions. The best place to ask those kinds of questions is
>   on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pedestal-users).
>
> Pedestal ships with its own utility for making requests directly to
>   the servlet (similar to ring/mock, although I've never used mock
>   myself) called [response-for](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/service/src/io/pedestal/test.clj#L260-L273). The Pedestal Service template produces a
>   test automatically for you. Check out one of the [samples](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/samples/hello-world/test/hello_world/service_test.clj) for an
>   example.

Also note that said `response-for` doesn't yet support asynchronous responses (so my routes that uses asynchronous interceptors with `core.async` failed - I had to make them synchronous).